# Angular active route parameter subscription not updating

Tags: angular

I'm having a strange problem where one of my route parameter subscription will stop updating when navigating to a particular route in Angular 7.

Here's my router config -

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OrganisationsRootComponent,
    canActivate: [RequireAuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'new',
        component: NewOrganisationComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: ListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':id/settings',
        component: OrganisationSettingsComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which is lazy loaded -

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'organisations', loadChildren: './organisations/organisations.module#OrganisationsModule' },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'organisations', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'organisations' },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

And my root component -

```
export class OrganisationsRootComponent implements OnInit {

  organisationId: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.firstChild.params.subscribe(params => {

      this.organisationId = params['id'];

      console.log('org id', this.organisationId);
  }

}
```

Now when I navigate to `organisations/1` or `organisations/2` the id is logged to the console. However if I navigate to `organisations/2/settings` or `organisations/new` the subscription stops working, even when navigating back to `organisations/1` or `organisations/2` nothing is being logged.

Would someone be able to explain why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug, while you navigate to 'organisations/2/settings', what's your firstChild info and current route info?

And if you subscribe to router events, you can listen to all router navigation changes instead of firstChild.

```
    import { NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';

  private routeSub:any;  // subscription to route observer

  public ngOnInit() {

    this.routeSub = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // listen for changes 
      }
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: The router events subscription is working ok but it is harder get obtain the organisation id that way. What would I be looking for in the debug info?